# How to manage sign in with apple functionality on laravel project?

Tags: laravel, apple-sign-in

I have a trouble signing users into my Laravel (API) application with Apple.
I already have functionality sign in with Facebook and Google but i didn't get any information about sign with apple.

Example with Facebook and Google sign in functionality.

```
 $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={$access_token}";

 $result = CurlHelper::exec($url, 'GET', null, [], [
     CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY
 ]);

 $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?idToken={$access_token}";

    $result = CurlHelper::exec($url, 'GET', null);
```

Comment: Have you tried to query google for "laravel apple sign in" i.e?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the idea from here

https://sarunw.com/posts/sign-in-with-apple-3/

Specific to laravel you can use this or use the logic and mold your code as per your requiremnts

https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-sign-in-with-apple